# How to pass an updated value to a nested directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive with some boilerplate html, including a menu toggle button.

Within that directive (transcluded) is one of a number of different nested directives, each with it's own menu.

The outer directive has an isolated scope and the inner directive has no scope specified.

When I click the menu toggle button on the outer directive, I want to be able to show/hide the menu contained in the inner directive.

How do I communicate the change in the toggle value from the outer directive to the inner directive?

I have tried broadcasting the change in the outer directive and listening for it in the inner directive, but that doesn't seem to work.

I have tried requiring the outer directive in the inner directive - I can see the value of the toggle there, but don't see a way of watching it for changes.

Here's the link function from the outer directive:

```
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
  var menuCollapsed = true;
  $scope.toggleMenu = function(){
    menuCollapsed = !menuCollapsed;
    console.log("ToggleMenu",menuCollapsed);
    $scope.$broadcast('menuCollapsed', menuCollapsed);
  };
}
```

and the inner directive contains this:

```
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, widgetCtrl){
  $scope.$on('menuCollapsed', function(event, args){
    console.log('menuCollapsed', event, args);
  });
```

The log in the outer directive displays, but not the one in the inner directive.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or plunkr

Answer (score 0):

if you use scope.emit the event will bubble up if you use scope.broadcast the event will be broadcasted down your tree. 
I persoanly  prefer events over watchers how ever if your child directive is a direct child of your parents directive scope, you can use standard data binding  in your child dierctive attributes.
to require a parent directive in a child directive, the parent directive has to expose its API through its controller function.
those are hints for more detailed help i would need to see some code

Comment: I am using scope.$emit to bubble up successfully in both directives, but $broadcast doesn't seem to bubble down. I don't have a scope definition in the inner directive. Is there something I need to include in the scope of the outer directive to get this to work?

Comment: so your inner directive doesn't generates an isolated scope? if this is the case this means you are using the same scope as the parent directive so you have all its scope variables at hand, you then need to set a watcher using scope.$watch('variableName'). thi works if you are wtching for a primitive value if you are watching for an object it only works if the object changes its address, so youll have to use a function that verifies for the objects property you want to check.

Comment: I tried that: 

outer: 
      $scope.menuCollapsed = true;
      $scope.toggleMenu = function(){
        $scope.menuCollapsed = !$scope.menuCollapsed;
        console.log("ToggleMenu",$scope.menuCollapsed);
      };
inner:


      $scope.$watch('menuCollapsed', function(newVal, oldVal){
        console.log('menuCollapsed', newVal, oldVal);
      });

Same result

Comment: btw, I think scope.$watchCollection will watch a whole object

Comment: maybe, i just really don't like watching entire objects. yes that won't work try using scope.watch(function(){return scope.menuCollapsed}),function(val1,val2){});

Comment: i just notices your menuCollapsed variable is not an scope variable. so it can't be watched or reached since is a private variable to your link function

Comment: where are you looking? it is a scope variable.

Comment: your directive definition it says var menuCollapsed = true; and then the update menuCollapsed = !menuCollapsed; those are not scope variables those are priate variables to the link function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52783/discussion-between-kpg-and-dayan-moreno-leon)